# How can we create single helper function for core data and sqlite

Tags: sqlite, core-data

I want to create a single helper class which is work for both sqlite and core data for fetching and manipulating data in my application.Is that possible?

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea, mainly for these reasons:

1. There is most likely no compelling reason to use the Core Data and SQLite APIs in the same project.
2. By combining two technologies in one class you are reducing the probability of being able to reuse them, violating the principle of [encapsulation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Articles/ooObjectModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005149-CH5-SW10).

That being said - you could have two helper classes that do certain things in SQLite and Core Data, and a combination class that calls methods from these two.

Difficult to say this would make any sense in a realistic project environment.